# Error: Address is not allowed while deploying Flink kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I am trying to install flink kubernetes operator on EKS using helm But it is throwing me same error for 1.6 and 1.7.0 version.

I have tried cert-manager 1.8.2 and 1.12.7 both

Reproduce Steps:

1. helm repo add flink-operator-repo https://downloads.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-1.7.0/       -n flink
2. helm install  flink-kubernetes-operator flink-operator-repo/flink-kubernetes-operator   --namespace flink --debug

```
install.go:214: [debug] Original chart version: ""

client.go:142: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
install.go:168: [debug] CRD flinkdeployments.flink.apache.org is already present. Skipping.
client.go:142: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
install.go:168: [debug] CRD flinksessionjobs.flink.apache.org is already present. Skipping.
client.go:142: [debug] creating 14 resource(s)
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: 2 errors occurred:
    * Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": Address is not allowed
    * Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": Address is not allowed
```

My flink-operator pod also in ContainerCreating state with following Error:

```
Warning   FailedMount         pod/flink-kubernetes-operator-7bdcc785dd-j76l2    MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "keystore" : secret "webhook-server-cert" not found
```